# Raspberry-PI system smart control through android apps

Tags: raspberry-pi

How can smartly/remotely control a Raspberry-PI system through android apps. I have found an android app named "Raspberry Control" ([source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skalski.raspberry.control)). I have followed all the steps as given in the above URL.

I have installed the android app in my phone (samsung galaxy note, recent release in 2014) followed tried to make a connection of android app with my RPI system (I have followed the steps mentioned in [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbcCQ7MHcuc)). But as shown in video, when the app started from phone, it needs a SSH connection (showed at 0.25 in the video). Unfortunately, I have faced an error like "check installation on RPi".

Thanks in advance for your precious time. Do I need to install any software on raspberry pi or am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 0):

> Secure Shell (SSH) is a network protocol that allows data to be
>   exchanged over a secure channel between two computers. Encryption
>   provides confidentiality and integrity of data. SSH uses public-key
>   cryptography to authenticate the remote computer and allow the remote
>   computer to authenticate the user, if necessary. SSH is typically used
>   to log into a remote machine and execute commands, but it also
>   supports tunneling, forwarding arbitrary TCP ports and X11
>   connections; file transfer can be accomplished using the associated
>   SFTP or SCP protocols. An SSH server, by default, listens on the
>   standard TCP port 22. An SSH client program is typically used for
>   establishing connections to an sshd daemon accepting remote
>   connections. Both are commonly present on most modern operating
>   systems, including Mac OS X, GNU/Linux, Solaris and OpenVMS.
>   Proprietary, freeware and open source versions of various levels of
>   complexity and completeness exist.
>   -Wiki

You found a complete guide/dossier in [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell) link. The install instruction can change depending on the system.

You can control rpi trought ssh simply from windows, linux, android, iOs using a ssh telnet/client. Your app simply after press a button send to rpi the correct ssh comand.

If you have debian(or raspbian) this guide is for you:https://wiki.debian.org/en/SSH.

So, **you must enable the ssh service on your rpi**. Username and password are user/pass of your rpi account.